# GRUB bootloader doesn't show up for new Ubuntu Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have three disks on my computer: `HDD`, `SSD1` and `SSD2`.

I have Windows installed on SSD1. I recently got `SSD2` and decided to remove the installation of Ubuntu I had on `HDD`.

I got my USB with Ubuntu 18.04 iso and wiped the partitions on the `HDD` using the Ubuntu installation process. I then made new `/`, `/home` and swap partitions on `SSD2`.

When I went to boot back up, GRUB was gone. I just boot directly into whichever OS the BIOS boot order specifies. I can now only switch between OSes by holding F12 on startup and selecting which drive to boot from.

This isn't that bad, but I would prefer to boot using GRUB and I'm kind of confused as to where GRUB has gone. There's also a mysterious entry third boot entry in the BIOS: `(ubuntu) SSD1`. It's an Ubuntu boot entry for the Windows SSD, but when you select that entry to boot from it just brings you back to the BIOS.

Any guidance on how I might tackle the issue?

Comment: Did you install in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? All systems need to be installed in same boot mode. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to open a terminal in Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. GRUB will detect other bootable devices on your computer (in this case, SSD1 with Windows) and should display your Windows installation in the terminal output.

Next, you should change the GRUB configuration file located at `/etc/default/grub` by running `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` (or replace `gedit` with another editor if you prefer or don't have gedit). Find the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and set the value to the number of seconds you want the GRUB menu to display when you first boot:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10   # 10 seconds for example
```

If you don't see a line with `GRUB_TIMEOUT`, go ahead and add a new line anywhere on this file.